# How using a local object reference is thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I read [a tutorial by jakob jenkov](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/thread-safety.html) states,

```
public void someMethod(){

  LocalObject localObject = new LocalObject();

  localObject.callMethod();
  method2(localObject);
}

public void method2(LocalObject localObject){
  localObject.setValue("value");
}
```

to be thread safe. But I think

```
public class LocalObject extends Thread {
    public void run(){
        //LocalObject a= new LocalObject();
        method2(this);
    }

    public void someMethod(){
        LocalObject localObject = new LocalObject();

        localObject.callMethod();
        method2(localObject);
    }

    public void method2(LocalObject localObject){
        localObject.setValue("value");
    }
    public void setValue(String s){

    }
    public void callMethod(){

    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        LocalObject a= new LocalObject();
        a.start();
        a.method2(a);
    }

}
```

is not thread thread safe as two thread 1. `main` & 2. `LocalObject`'s thread is accessing the method2, which has a method `setValue`
Where have I misunderstood it?

Comment: Notice that new local instance of `LocalObject` is created in the `someMethod()`. That's why it's being thread safe..

Comment: An object used by only one thread is thread safe as there is no chance you can have a threading issue with multiple threads.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Seems like a well expressed question to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The misunderstanding stems from the fact, that while there are two threads calling mathod2() at the same time, they are calling t on **different instances** of the class `LocalObject`:

```
public void run(){
    LocalObject a= new LocalObject(); //this is a new instance 
    method2(a);
}


public static void main(String args[]){
    LocalObject a= new LocalObject(); //this is an antirelz different instance
    a.start(); 
    a.method2(a);
}
```

If it was like

```
public void run(){
    //YIKES - not thread safe -- method 2 can be called from outside!
    method2(this); 
}
```

Then there would be an issue... But this would not pertain to the example in anz ways.

Comment: By the way, every instance of `LocalObject` can mess with static fields. So there is no safety guarantee.

Comment: @ppeterka Sorry, I meant to be like public void run(){
    method2(this);
} This is not thread safe Right?

Comment: @RajeshKumar if the `run` method references `this` -- that is not thread safe anymore

Answer (score 0):

First off, any time you create an object and store the object reference ONLY in an "automatic" variable (a variable declared within a method), and where you never later store that reference value into some other non-automatic location, that object can never "escape" from the thread where it was created.  It does not matter if you pass the reference as a parameter to other methods (that observe the above restriction), since they are necessarily in the same thread.

And any object which is only referenced from a single thread is inherently "thread safe".

Similarly, if you have an instance of a subclass of Thread, and values (including possible references to other objects) are stored in that instance, this is "thread safe" so long as no other thread (including the initiating thread) is allowed to reference or modify the instance while the instance's thread is executing.  Other possible instances of the same subclass will be referencing their own instances, not the first one mentioned -- they each have their own private "playpen".

Thread safety only becomes an issue when two different threads can access the *same* object instance, not simply one by the same name or of the same class.